# Hi I'm a new in Java

Tags: netbeans

```js
public class MoviesData {
String Const;
String Your_Rating;
String Date_Rated;
String Title;
String URL;
String Title_Type;
String IMDb_Rating;
String Runtime_mins;
String Year;
String Genres;
String Num_Votes;
String Release_Date;
String Directors;

String filename="ratings.csv";

String ReadData(){    
    File file=new File(filename).getAbsoluteFile();
    file.getAbsolutePath();
    String data = null;
    try{
    Scanner S=new Scanner(file);
    S.nextLine();
    S.useDelimiter(",\n");
    while(S.hasNext())
    {
        data=data+S.next();    
    }
    S.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace()[0]);               }
    return data;
    //String Data=data.replace(",","-");
```

```js
  ArrayList<MoviesData> MD=new ArrayList<MoviesData>();
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
MoviesData m=new MoviesData();

String L=m.ReadData();
String[] M=L.split(",");
m.Const=M[0]; m.Your_Rating=M[1]; m.Date_Rated=M[2]; m.Title=M[3]; m.URL=M[4]; m.Title_Type=M[5];
m.IMDb_Rating=M[6]; m.Runtime_mins=M[7]; m.Year=M[8]; m.Genres=M[9]; m.Num_Votes=M[10]; 
m.Release_Date=M[11];m.Directors=M[12];
System.out.println(L);
```

i field has many , between "" i want to chance it 
I have String like this (6.2,108,1990,"Action, Horror, Sci-Fi, Thriller",119935,) want to change the , only between "" not all , i get the String from Scanner CSv file

Answer (score -2):

Well I'm pretty stupid so I can't tell exactly what you want but I can guess, if you are asking how you could put anything into a String, you can convert it into a String, a character will go in since it is compatible, for putting in something like a double or an int you can use the Interger.parseInt() and Double.parseDouble() methods like String new = Double.parseDouble(5); but I am probably not understanding the question so If I did than feel free to ignore this answer.

Comment: Sorry for bad explain I have String like this (6.2,108,1990,"Action, Horror, Sci-Fi, Thriller",119935,) want to change the , only between "" not all ,

Comment: i get the String from Scanner CSv file and but it in String

Comment: Well there is a .replace() method you can use for that, like String 
 = String.replace(","," ");

Comment: this method will replace the only , between "" not All

Comment: Well for that have you though of making a subString of the things between the "" and then replacing the original with that substring

Comment: sure one sec tho

Comment: public class StringReplacer{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  String string = "6.2,108,1990,\"Action, Horror, Sci-Fi, Thriller\",119935,";
  String replaced = null;
  String substring = string.substring(string.indexOf("\""), string.lastIndexOf("\""));
  System.out.println(substring);
  substring = substring.replace(",", " ");
  System.out.println(substring);
  String finalString = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("\"")) + substring + string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("\""), string.length());
  System.out.println(finalString);
 }
}

Comment: Sorry you put \ manual it's big data my IMDB.com data and i want to modify it automatically to put each part in variables but thank you for your help

Comment: @DaHomieAdamand please don't use comment section to post code answers. [edit] the answer instead.